# Get list of top 3 owners with the most activities per each week in year 2021

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Task:

**Get list of top 3 owners with the most activities per each week in year 2021**

Hint: TOP, GROUP BY, COUNT, Convert Date in Week Number, ROW_NUMBER

Output:

Week Number

OwnerId

OwnerIdName

Count**

**The first day of the week is Monday (not Sunday)**

I got this code, it works

```
DECLARE @date date = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0,DATEADD(week, 0, '2021')), 0) ;
DECLARE @datend date = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, -5,DATEADD(week,43, '2021')), -1) ;

SELECT
TOP (3)
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Datepart(week, a.ModifiedOn) ORDER BY COUNT(a.ActivityId) DESC),

Datepart(week, a.ModifiedOn) AS Week,
a.OwnerId,
a.OwneridName,
COUNT(a.ActivityId) AS Count
FROM ActivityPointer AS a 
WHERE 
a.ModifiedOn >= @date
AND
a.ModifiedOn <= @datend
AND
a.ActivityTypeCode IN ('4201','4210','4212') 
AND a.OwnerId IN('3C696B18-BFF4-E911-A68A-005056A18C45',  
'DDD1597F-4FCD-E411-80D3-0050568973A1',   
'0AD3654A-7517-E011-B418-00505689002A',   
'98FA2C51-A296-EB11-A6AD-005056A18C45',   
'56C940A2-B396-EB11-A6AD-005056A18C45',   
'379C0CE5-D3D2-E911-8105-02BF0A0AC819') 
GROUP BY a.OwnerId,a.OwneridName,Datepart(week, a.ModifiedOn)
```

But unfortunately it does not give me the result I need

Comment: What is a "buna no", @BogdanSahlean ? Also, it's `ORDER BY` (there is a space, and only 1 `Y`).

Comment: As for the problem, note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results. For your results, this is likely why you aren't getting the data you want; you don't have an `ORDER BY` and so the data engine is free to return 3 **arbitrary** rows.

Comment: @Larnu And what about `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Datepart(week, a.ModifiedOn) ORDER BY COUNT(a.ActivityId) DESC)`  I put ORDER BY and GroupBY here.

Comment: That effects the order of the `ROW_NUMBER` expression, not the result set.

Comment: Sample data and expected results, in a consumable format (*not* an image) will help us help you, I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using TOP(), use generated row_number() from window function will give what you want. see the following code as an example:

```
DECLARE @date date = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0,DATEADD(week, 0, '2021')), 0) ;
DECLARE @datend date = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, -5,DATEADD(week,43, '2021')), -1) ;

WITH sorted_list AS (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Datepart(week, a.ModifiedOn) ORDER BY COUNT(a.ActivityId) DESC) as row_num,    
Datepart(week, a.ModifiedOn) AS Week,
a.OwnerId,
a.OwneridName,
COUNT(a.ActivityId) AS COUNT_NUM
FROM ActivityPointer AS a 
WHERE 
a.ModifiedOn >= @date
AND
a.ModifiedOn <= @datend
AND
a.ActivityTypeCode IN ('4201','4210','4212') 
AND a.OwnerId IN('3C696B18-BFF4-E911-A68A-005056A18C45',  
'DDD1597F-4FCD-E411-80D3-0050568973A1',   
'0AD3654A-7517-E011-B418-00505689002A',   
'98FA2C51-A296-EB11-A6AD-005056A18C45',   
'56C940A2-B396-EB11-A6AD-005056A18C45',   
'379C0CE5-D3D2-E911-8105-02BF0A0AC819') 
GROUP BY a.OwnerId,a.OwneridName,Datepart(week, a.ModifiedOn)
)
SELECT
Week,
OwnerId,
OwneridName,
COUNT_NUM
FROM
sorted_list
WHERE
row_num <=3
ORDER BY
Week, row_num
```